# Update MS Access Marquee text on each loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I admit to being a bit of a novice, but have designed myself a very handy personal MS Access database. I have tried to find a solution to the following on the net, but have been unsuccessful so far, hence my post (the first time I've done this).

I have a marquee on a form in MS Access, which scrolls the count of "incomplete tasks" to do. A "Tasks COUNT Query" provides a number from zero upwards. After the form loads, the code below scrolls a message (right to left) on the marquee in the form "There are X tasks requiring action." X is the number provided from the "Tasks COUNT Query". I would like the text string on the marquee to update on each loop, so that when I mark a task as complete, the next pass on the marquee shows the number (X) as being the updated count.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Number As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Tasks COUNT Query")

If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
Do While Not rst.EOF
Number = rst![Tasks]
strTxt = strTxt & "There are " & Number & " tasks requiring action."
rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If
rst.Close
strTxt = Left(strTxt, Len(strTxt)) 'remove the coma at the end
strTxt = Space(30) & strTxt 'start position

Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Me.TimerInterval = 180

End Sub
```

**The following code runs on the form timer interval:**

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Dim x

On Error GoTo Form_Timer_Err

x = Left(strTxt, 1)
strTxt = Right(strTxt, Len(strTxt) - 1)
strTxt = strTxt & x
lblMarqTask.Caption = Left(strTxt, 180)
Exit Sub
Form_Timer_Exit:
Exit Sub

Form_Timer_Err:
Me.TimerInterval = 0
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I would be grateful for any assistance :)

Comment: Kudos for giving it (VBA) a shot and getting this far, and for asking a nice clear question!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement Gary. I'm tinkering with it bit by bit, and will hopefully get there.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question: -

> I would like the text string on the marquee to update on each loop

To do this you need to place your code that collects the string into its own procedure and then pick a time to call it. I.e.

Move the `Form_Load()` code into its own procedure

```
Private Sub GetString()
Dim db As DAO.Database
... [The remaining code] ...
Me.TimerInterval = 180
End Sub
```

Change `Form_Load()` to call the new procedure

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
GetString
End Sub
```

Have the timer call the new procedure every so often to update the marquee (also known as ticker tape).

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Dim x
Static LngTimes As Long

On Error GoTo Form_Timer_Err

LngTimes = LngTimes + 1
If LngTimes = 100 Then
    GetString
    LngTimes = 0
End If

x = Left(StrTxt, 1)
StrTxt = Right(StrTxt, Len(StrTxt) - 1)
StrTxt = StrTxt & x
lblMarqTask.Caption = Left(StrTxt, 180)
Exit Sub
Form_Timer_Exit:
Exit Sub
```

This will update it every 100 times the timer runs. I have tested this and it works, albeit causing a judder in marquee scrolling.

I would like to take the time to give you some extra support in your code that may help understand VBA and make things clearer/easier for you in any future development.

The changes I have supplied are minimal to give you the desired result within the code you have currently. However it does mean I carried some issue across with it. I would perform the same feature with the below: -

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private StrStatus   As String

Private Sub GetStatus()
Dim Rs  As DAO.Recordset

Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT count([Task]) FROM [TblTasks] WHERE [Done] = 'No'")
    StrStatus = "There are " & Rs(0) & " tasks requiring action."
    Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.TimerInterval = 180
Me.lblMarqTask.Caption = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
Static StrStatus_Lcl    As String

If StrStatus_Lcl = "" Then
    GetStatus
    StrStatus_Lcl = StrStatus & Space(30)
    If Me.lblMarqTask.Caption = "" Then Me.lblMarqTask.Caption = Space(Len(StrStatus_Lcl))
End If

Me.lblMarqTask.Caption = Right(Me.lblMarqTask.Caption, Len(Me.lblMarqTask.Caption) - 1) & Left(StrStatus_Lcl, 1)
StrStatus_Lcl = Right(StrStatus_Lcl, Len(StrStatus_Lcl) - 1)

End Sub
```

The result is the string scrolling will remain smooth the value get updates with each iteration.

To talk through what I have done here.

'Option Explicit' Is always good practice to have at the top of your modules/code, it forces you to declare your variables which can save you a headache in the future. This can be automatically added with new code object by enabling 'Require Variable Declaration' in 'Tools' > 'Options' of the VBA Developer environment (also known as the VBE).

Its not clear what the query was doing but to save on a loop I change it to return a single value that I could use. `SELECT count([Task]) FROM [TblTasks] WHERE [Done] = 'No'` will return a count of all items in `TblTasks` where the column `Done` equals `No`.

In format load I set the timer interval as this only needs setting once and I also ensured the marquee was empty before it run.

The timer keeps a local copy of the status that it remembers. Declaring with the word `Static` means the content of the variable is not lost between executions in the way a `Dim` declared variable would be.

If the local copy is empty (i.e. we have used it all up) then update what the status is (`GetStatus`) and get a new copy.

I hope this has been of help!